# Google Maps integrated with fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, maps, fancybox

Can somebody please how me understand why the google map is not working in fancybox? I have included my code below.

My JS

```
var fbCloseTitle = "close",
fbNextTitle = "next",
fbPrevTitle = "previous";$(".fancybox").fancybox({
width: '90%',
height: '90%',
fixed: false,
autoSize: false,
autoCenter: true,
tpl: {
    closeBtn: '<div title="' + fbCloseTitle + '" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close"></div>',
    next: '<a title="' + fbNextTitle + '" class="fancybox-item fancybox-next"><span></span></a>',
    prev: '<a title="' + fbPrevTitle + '" class="fancybox-item fancybox-prev"><span></span></a>'
}});
```

My HTML

```
<div class="cul center apear floatL">

 <div class="verticalLine"></div>
    <figure class="diamond relative"> <a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=big%20smile%20creative+Cambridge,+UK"><img class="centerAbsolute" src="img/diamond04.jpg" alt="Graphic Design In Cambridge"></a></figure>
    <h2 class="proximaBold">we work in the heart of cambridge!</h2>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <p>We are very proud of our city and we try to provide a good, honest, local service that the businesses of Cambridge can rely on. You deserve it!</p>
  </div>
```

I think maybe my google maps url is wrong, the fancybox works fine, its just the map is not loading from google maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you share the map from Google, you should actually get the second link (`iframe` tag) *Paste HTML to embed in website*, then extract the value of the iframe's `src` attribute and use it in your anchor's `href` like

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=big+smile+creative+Cambridge,+UK&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=big+smile+creative&amp;hnear=Cambridge,+United+Kingdom&amp;ll=52.205336,0.121817&amp;spn=0.027297,0.084543&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A&amp;cid=16361723521191055041&amp;output=embed">google map</a>
```

Then, in your fancybox script, I would advice you to disable the iframe `preload` to avoid some known issues like the map off center so :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    iframe: {
        preload: false
    }
});
```

See <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/y8LLx/2/)</kbd>